# How to invoke overriden method of super class from static method of child class in java

Tags: java, inheritance, static-methods, super, superclass

Overridden methods of super class can be accessed from a child class using the keyword `super` but the child class method that is invoking the super class method must be non-static. How can I invoke super class overridden from a static method of child class.

```
class TakeMe{
    
    void display(){
        System.out.println("In super");
    }

}

public class Inher extends TakeMe{

    void display(){
        System.out.println("In child");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Inher obj = new Inher();
        super.display();     //Error here
    }
}
```

This shows error `Cannot use super in a static contextJava(536871112)`

`obj.super.display()` doesn't work

Comment: You can’t do that. Why do you think you would want to? PS How could `obj.a` work? I see no `a` anywhere.

Comment: Oh that `a` was a copy paste error. My bad

Comment: The short answer is that static methods are not inherited.

Comment: In Java, the only place you can call a super method is from within an instance method (so in a `static` method you cannot, and `main()` is `static`). In C++ it’s different if my memory serves me right.

Comment: One way to think of it is, that’s what *override* means. The override takes effect so the way the method was defined in the superclass isn’t valid any more (except in instance methods of the inherited class because that’s where you make the override, and being able to connect the two is fair and needed).

Answer (score 1):

Usage of super() inside the display() method is incorrect. Try this instead:

```
class TakeMe {
    void display() {
        System.out.println("In super");
    }
}

public class Inher extends TakeMe {
    void display() {
        super.display(); // <- here
        System.out.println("In child");
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Inher obj = new Inher();
        obj.display();     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is following;

```
class TakeMe{
    
    void display(){
        System.out.println("In super");
    }

}

public class Inher extends TakeMe{

    void display(){
        super();
        System.out.println("In child");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Inher obj = new Inher();
        obj.display();     
    }
}
```